# Search bar not showing up on the navigation bar iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am pushing a viewController where I want a searchBar, but search bar is not showing at all. Below is the code. Am I missing something?

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here..."
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    navigationItem.titleView?.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: I used your code it is working

Comment: How you are pushing new view controller?

Comment: I am using this - let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"someVC")
vc.show(destinationVC, sender: self)

Comment: This got solved by adding this line - navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

Comment: Now the problem is the search bar is coming below the navigationBar. How can we have searchbar on top of navigation bar?

Comment: I dont think you can have it above the navigation bar unless you create your own

Comment: You can hide the navigation bar whilst searching using `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true`

Comment: Did you find the solution? @AjayKumar

Answer (score 14):

You need to add this line to your code:

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

That removes hiding searchBar while scrolling and shows it on pushing your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

So, `navigationItem.hidesSearchWhenScrolling` only works when you set the `searchController` property of `navigationItem` NOT when you set the `navigationItem.titleView` to `searchBar`.